# MATLAB video capture & image processing without the Image Acquisition Toolbox

Tags: matlab

I would like to capture a live video in MATLAB and take picture frames from it, upon which image processing will be done to identify certain colours in the environment

I do not have the Image Acquisition Toolbox, I only have Image Processing Toolbox. The methods I know use the Image Acquisition toolbox functions.

Comment: I have no idea about a matlab based solution, but with Opencv ( with or without python) you most certainly can write a little program that captures and processes the initial video feed.

Comment: well, there's a reason they make the IA Toolbox... if you have Labview, you can embed your processing m-code into the acquisition aspect of labview to capture the live stream, or follow @Maurits' idea and use OCV to capture and compile m to c code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try these fex options:

1. [Simple Video Camera Frame Grabber Toolkit](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/35554-simple-video-camera-frame-grabber-toolkit)
2. [VCAPG2](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/2939-vcapg2)
3. [Video Adaptor device (webcam) setup for MATLAB](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/24891-image-aquisition)

Comment: thanks I believe these work without the toolbox. I just have a problem running them as they give errors. The VCAPG2 solution gives me the error:
Undefined function 'vcapg2' for input arguments of type 'double'. I simply took the dll file and put it in the same directory as the m file and just ran the m file. Are there further instructions to carry out first? I've tried on MATLAB R2008 and R2011b and I'm getting the same error.

Comment: @elefante check that you have installed DirectX runtime libraries. The most updated source code and dll can be found in this link:  http://www.ikko.k.hosei.ac.jp/~matlab/matkatuyo/vcapg2_release.zip

Comment: thanks a lot it works fine now. Both VCAPG2 and the Frame Grabber solutions are working. I appreciate.